# Getting an object to travel at 35 to 45 mph

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm doing a project which simulates a car accident, with a cube block which has sensors on it crashing into a wall. 
This object is on a 3 m track mounted on a linear bearing to reduce friction.

So this object needs to be travelling at a speed and it impacts a solid wall (with about 40 G of deceleration in that impact). This impact is what I am recording.

My question is, how can I get this object to travel at that speed? (which is about 35 to 45 mph, if my math isn't wrong that is)

Comment: What is the mass of your object? Getting something light to travel at 15-20m/s is fairly straightforward, getting something heavy to do so is a different matter.

Comment: you would need an acceleration of 66m/s² to accelerate an object to 20m/s on a 3 meter track (unless I miscalculated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say we want 40 MPH (since I don't even have enough information to verify that it will give you the 40 G's).  As Olin mentioned, $40 MPH \approx 18 m/s$.

I feel like in this situation, a spring would be your best bet.  We want it to be travelling at 18 m/s at the end of the 3 m path.  Potential energy in a spring is: $$ PE = \frac{1}{2} K x^2 $$
where K is the spring constant and x is the spring displacement.
  We want to compare that to the kinetic energy required to get 18 m/s.  This is given by: $$ KE = \frac{1}{2} m v^2$$
where m is the mass of the object and v is the velocity of the object.  If we want to use all the potential energy in the spring to move the block, we can equate them:$$\frac{1}{2}K x^2 = \frac{1}{2}m v^2$$
Then cancelling some terms and rearranging:$$\frac{v^2}{x^2} = \frac{K}{m}$$ Using v = 18 m/s and x = 3 m: $$\left(\frac{18}{3}\left[\frac{1}{s}\right]\right)^2 = \frac{K}{m}$$ 
Simplifying and rearranging a little more: $$36 \left[\frac{1}{s^2}\right]\cdot m = K$$ 
So if your mass was 10 kg for example, then you need a spring with a spring constant $$K = 36 \left[\frac{1}{s^2} \right] \cdot 10 kg = 360 \left[\frac{N}{m}\right]$$

You can play around with the length of spring if you don't want it to travel the whole 3 m on a spring.  Obviously you can also adjust your mass accordingly depending on what it really is.  You could choose a tension or compression spring; whatever you feel would work best in your setup.

Answer (score 2):

First, start by using consistent units.  40 miles/hour is 18 m/s.  For steady acceleration, the average speed when starting at 0 is therefore 9 m/s.  You have 3 m of acceleration distance, so the acceleration time is ⅓ second.  That means the acceleration is 54 m/s<sup>2</sup>.  That's about 5½ g.  How much force and energy that requires depends on the mass that is being accelerated.  Note that this includes anything the accelerating mass is riding on, like a sled on the track.

You haven't said anything about the mass of the object, so I'll just pick 10 kg to see what that requires.  The final kinetic energy is:

E = ½ m V<sup>2</sup> = ½ (10 kg)(18 m/s)<sup>2</sup> = 1.6 kJ

Since that needs to imparted over 1/3 s, the power required is 4.9 kW.  The right electric motor with the right power source could do this, but something like a pneumatic piston is probably easier.

Another option is to let gravity do the acceleration if you're not absolutely stuck with 3 m of level track.  In 1 g gravity as here on earth, a 16.5 m drop results in 18 m/s terminal speed and takes 1.8 seconds.  This 16.5 meters drop doesn't need to be straight down.

If you can arrange for a track that slopes down with a total drop of 17 m with maybe a small straight run-out section at the bottom, a lot of things get simpler.  The acceleration is independent of the mass.  Nothing needs to be adjusted as more or less gets piled onto the sled.  One way or another, you still have to supply the energy.  However, now you're supplying it by hoisting the sled up to the top.  This doesn't have to be done as fast, so you can trade off power with how long you're willing to wait.  It's also mechanically easier since the hoisting system won't be envolved in the crash.  It could be as simple as a cable and a crank, with some sort of release mechanism at the top.

Comment: Mr. Troublemaker says:  is that the average speed with respect to position or with respect to time?  [devilish grin] .

Comment: @Carl: I'm not following what you're trying to say.  Did I mess up units somewhere?

Comment: no it's just that there are two different possible averages you can calculate, and they indicate different things.  In most cases we want the average with respect to time, which is what you calculated.  However, if you calculate the average w.r.t. position, since position goes as square of time, you'll get a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really calculate the G-force for two rigid objects, as the collision is nearly a delta function.  If you want to simulate the force on, say, the driver inside a car, then you have to model the rate of deceleration as the front of the car collapses -- which is strongly dependent on the total vehicle design.  As an historical note, Volvo back in the 60s and 70s ran ads showing their car being dropped nose-first off a roof, and retaining the basic frame shape after hitting the ground.  That's great for rigidity, but then everyone realized this just transferred the peak impulse deceleration straight to the occupants. After that, cars' designs were modified to dissipate as much energy as possible by completely destroying the front end up to the firewall. This greatly reduces the peak G-force on the passenger compartment.

So, back to your block-to-wall experiment: unless your block is collapsible, you're going to be doing the 1970s Volvo thing.  You may want to modify your experiment in light of this.